# Как строится DOM JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, request, cheerio

Вообще не понимаю как этот DOM строится, пытаюсь на простом сайте запарсить данные и то не получается .
вот исохдные данные. Моя задача выписать { инструкция, отзывы, О магазине...} в отдельный массив

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Переключить навигацию</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand nav-logo" href="/">
            <img src="/assets/img/logo.png" />
            <span>Keys Store</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a class="navigation" href="/instruction.php">Инструкция</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="navigation" href="/reviews.php">Отзывы</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="navigation" href="/about.php">О магазине</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="navigation" href="/contacts.php">Контакты</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

а вот через библиотеку cheerio пытаюсь запарсить. если что мне именно надо в таком виде, через each(function(){

```
    var data ={};
$('div.class.id').each(function(){
     var text = ($(this).attr('a.navigation'));
     data.push(text);
   });
    console.log(data)
```

Comment: А что такое `div.class.id` в вашем html не видно ни одного div с именем класса `class`, а `.id` вообще не ясно к чему относится. вот если бы вы написали `div.collapse` или `div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` или даже просто `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` может чего и нашлось бы ... Вам надо начать с изучения селекторов https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Comment: так я знаю что я не правильно сделал) напишите как правильно тут надо

Comment: вроде разобрался)  $('ul .navigation').each(function(){
     var text = ($(this).text());

Comment: вот тока теперь проблема выдает в таком виде [ 'Инструкция', 'Отзывы', 'О магазине', 'Контакты' ] . как можно убрать запятые сверху '   ?

Comment: какие запятые ? у вас в массиве лежат сами значения. А console.log() при выводе заключает их в кавычки для наглядности